# javascript regex fix for not replacing image url

Tags: javascript, html, regex, string, replace

I am using regex to replace all `url` in string to `<a href="url">url</a>`.

For that I am using

```
if(!String.linkify) {
    String.prototype.linkify = function() {

        // http://, https://, ftp://
        var urlPattern = /\b(?:https?|ftp):\/\/[a-z0-9-+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[a-z0-9-+&@#\/%=~_|]/gim;

        // www. sans http:// or https://
        var pseudoUrlPattern = /(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))/gim;

        // Email addresses
        var emailAddressPattern = /[\w.]+@[a-zA-Z_-]+?(?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})+/gim;

        return this
            .replace(urlPattern, '<a href="$&">$&</a>')
            .replace(pseudoUrlPattern, '$1<a href="http://$2">$2</a>')
            .replace(emailAddressPattern, '<a href="mailto:$&">$&</a>');
    };
}
```

and

```
mystr.linkify();
```

it's from here , https://stackoverflow.com/a/7123542/1602333

it works good unless I have img tag in my string , it replaces

`<img src="imgurl"/>` to `<img src="<a href="imgurl">imgurl</a>"`

Which change should I do to my regex to not replace urls which are part of some tag attribute ?

Any help would be great.

Comment: Rule 1: don't use RegEx to parse HTML. Rule 2: if you still want to parse HTML with RegEx, see rule 1.

Comment: Have you tried the library mentioned in the first answer in the question you link to?

Comment: not actually, are you talking about http://benalman.com/projects/javascript-linkify/ ?

Comment: [Autolinker.js](https://github.com/gregjacobs/Autolinker.js). And the usage is simple: `var linkedText = Autolinker.link(input_html, { className: "myLink" } );`.

Comment: @MohammadhussainKhatri - stop jumping to conclusions, I didn't downvote

Comment: @stribizhev I didn't use that library. will try. Are you sure , it will not replace url in img tag ?

Comment: I have posted the answer with the description from the library readme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Autolinker.js`](https://github.com/gregjacobs/Autolinker.js), it is known to be reliable with linkifying.

See the description part about links inside other tags/attributes:

> **Will properly handle HTML input**. The utility **will not change** the `href` attribute inside anchor (`<a>`) tags (**or any other tag/attribute for that matter**), and will not accidentally wrap the inner text of an anchor tag with a new one (which would cause doubly-nested anchor tags).

Here is an example of using it:

```
var linkedText = Autolinker.link(input_html, { className: "myLink" } );
```

Comment: ok , trying , just a few minutes.

Comment: yes, it's working as expected. I couldn't find it even I refered to that question. Thank you.