# Generate HTML anchor by parsing text containing URLs

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have a paragraph containing running text that may also contain URLs. The paragraph would contain running text describing an object or thing and interleaved with URLs in between.
The URLs could be of the form of

1. http://mail.google.com
2. http://www.google.com
3. www.google.com

I need to parse the paragraph using JavaScript and generate an HTML content, making sure that the URLs are rendered as an HTML anchor. 
I could use following -

```
var httpUrlPattern = /https?:\/\/[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/\$~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?
text = text.replace( httpUrlPattern, '<a href="$&" target="_blank">$&</a>' );
```

This works fine for URLs of type #1) and #2). But for #3) it generates href=/www.google.com

so I apply additional filtering

```
var wwwUrlPattern = /(www\.)[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/\$~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?;
text = text.replace( wwwUrlPattern, '<a href="http://$&" target="_blank">$&</a>' );
```

This fixes #3) but breaks #2).

Any suggestion how can I fix all the scenarios?

Comment: Are you trying to wrap links with anchor tags? See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32584668/3832970).

Comment: Are the URLs on separate (on their own) lines?

Comment: @stribizhev: I get the links as plain text, I am wrapping it in an anchor so that they are clickable.

Comment: @ClasG, Unfortunately not. They can be anywhere in the paragraph.

Comment: @Abhi: Then, you do not have to re-invent the wheel, try the [Autolinker.js](https://github.com/gregjacobs/Autolinker.js) library.

Comment: @stribizhev: Thank you. I went through the Autolinker.js and this would definitely solve my problem. But incorporating a 3rd party JS library at my organization needs to go through chain of management approvals. I agree with you about not to re-invent the wheel, so I think that would my last resort if nothing else works out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lack of criteria for how the URL is constructed make it hard. I assume you wan't to catch URLs without the `www` or `mail` prefix, like `stackoverflow.com`. This makes the matching very uncertain. It could be something like though:

```
/\b[\w.,@?^=%&:/$~+#-]+\.\w\w+\b/
```

but there's a huge risk of false matches.

To make it more specific you could make either the `http` **or** the `www`/`mail` part (or/and any other given set of prefixes) mandatory:

```
/\b((?:https?:\/\/|www\.|mail\.)[\w.,@?^=%&:/$~+#-]+)\.\w\w+\b/
```

Hope this helps.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks, this expression worked for me. My apologies, I did not reply earlier. But it would not have been good etiquette not to reply, so I am replying even its few days have elapsed. Thanks again!

Comment: @Abhi Glad to hear it worked :) Maybe accept the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Nest the groups

```
var wwwUrlPattern = /(http:\/\/)?((www\.)[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/\$~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-]))?/;
text = text.replace( wwwUrlPattern, '<a href="http://$2" target="_blank">$&</a>' );
```